# Change n-th entry of NumPy array that fulfills condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have a NumPy array `arr` and an (inverse) mask `mask`. For simplicity let us assume they are both 1d. I want to change the `n`th non-masked value in `arr`.

An example:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.arange(5)
mask = np.array((True, False, True, True, False))
```

Unfortunately,

```
arr[mask][-1] = 100
```

which I expected to return

```
array([0, 1, 2, 100, 4])
```

does not work due to the reasons outlined in [NumPy array views on non-consecutive items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8285175/numpy-array-views-on-non-consecutive-items).

A workaround would be to store the allowed values in a new variable, change the respective value, and copy all values back into the original array:

```
tmp = arr[mask]
tmp[-1] = 100
arr[mask] = tmp
```

However, this solution is ugly and inefficient, since I have to copy many values that I do not want to change at all.

Does anyone have an elegant way to deal with this kind of problem? I would be interested in a maximally general solution, so that I could do all classic assignment operations with `tmp`. However, if there is an efficient way that works only for the concrete dscribed case, I would still be interested in it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to obtain the set of indices where your `mask` condition is `True`. You can then index into `arr` using a subset of these indices and make your assignment:

```
# np.where returns a tuple of index arrays, one per dimension
arr[np.where(mask)[0][-1]] = 100

print(repr(arr))
# array([  0,   1,   2, 100,   4])
```

You could combine this approach with slice indexing, boolean indexing etc. For example:

```
arr[np.where(mask)[0][::-1]] = 100, 200, 300
print(repr(arr))
# array([300,   1, 200, 100,   4])
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, @ali_m! It will be sufficient for my needs. What bothers me, though, is that I have to create an order of `arr.size` array in order to perform an action that should be doable with constant memory...

Answer (score 0):

You also could use [`np.nonzero`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) to get index from your mask?

```
index = mask.nonzero()[0][-1]

arr[index] = 100

In [29]: arr 
Out[29]: array([  0,   1,   2, 100,   4])
```

alternatively you could convert you `np.array` to list and use `index` method of the list to find index of the last value:

```
index = arr.tolist().index(arr[mask][-1])
arr[index] = 100

In [78]: arr
Out[78]: array([  0,   1,   2, 100,   4])
```

**Benchmarking**:

```
In [87]: %timeit arr[mask.nonzero()[0][-1]] = 100
1000000 loops, best of 3: 897 ns per loop

In [88]: %timeit arr[np.where(mask)[0][-1]] = 100
1000000 loops, best of 3: 980 ns per loop

In [91]: %timeit arr[arr.tolist().index(arr[mask][-1])] = 100
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.44 us per loop
```

So `nonzero` method is a bit faster than `np.where`.

**EDIT**

I think `nonzero` is a bit faster because for [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) from docs:

> If only *condition* is given, return `condition.nonzero()`.

So basically you're callin `np.nonzero` but through `np.where` because in that case you passing only a condition.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative `nonzero`, @Anton - though I do not really understand, why it is faster...

Comment: I think it because `nonzero` is called from `np.where`